# Why doesn't Observable.Buffer with bufferClosingSelector work

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

**EDIT:**

Closing this one because I was an **Idiot** and didn't realize that my `GetLogEntries()` method was buggy: I did some time computations in there, and instead of using `TimeSpan.TotalMilliSeconds`, I was using `TimeSpan.Milliseconds`.
Yeah.

**Original Question:**

Given the following 4 methods, where the 3 first work just fine, but the last doesn't, I can't figure out why the last one doesn't.

- Case1() *works:* just buffers events with a given TimeStamp
- Case2() *works:* buffers events with an Observable, using a [bufferClosingSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229432(v=vs.103).aspx)
- Case3() *works:* just buffers events with a given TimeStamp
- Case4() ***does not work:*** buffers events with an Observable, using a [bufferClosingSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229432(v=vs.103).aspx)

I just can't figure out why TestCase4() doesn't work. Am I missing something?

```cs
public void Case1()
{
    var a = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    var b = a.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    b.Subscribe(x =>
    {
        // yep, this is called every second
    });
}

public void Case2()
{
    var a = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    var b = a.Buffer(() => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));

    b.Subscribe(x =>
    {
        // yep, this is also called every second
    });
}

public void Case3()
{
    IObservable<LogEntry> source = this.LogsProvider.GetLogEntries();
    var buffered = source.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    buffered.Subscribe(logentriesList =>
    {
        // yep, I get an IList<LogEntry> each second.
    });
}

public void Case4()
{
    IObservable<LogEntry> source = this.LogsProvider.GetLogEntries();
    var buffered = source.Buffer(() => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));

    buffered.Subscribe(logentriesList =>
    {
        // nope, I never get here.. Why ? Case3() works as expected... 
        // Isn't this just the same as Case2() vs Case1(), where Case2() actually works? 
    });
}
```

Comment: How can anyone help you to debug your code if you exclude the most important parts?  Instead of posting code that works for you, why not just post all of the code that doesn't in a [short but complete program](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html)?

Comment: I was intrigued by the fact that case 3 worked as expected, so I assumed my GetLogEntries() method "just worked"™. That's why ommited it in my original question. I thought that maybe I was missing some conceptual (aka voodoo) differences between case 3 and 4. Of course I was just an idiot and apologize. Of course my GetLogEntries was fu..... up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementations of the two overloads of `Buffer()` you are experimenting with are (unsurprisingly) quite different - but I think this is a red herring. The outcome should be the same given the way you are using them.

As Dave Sexton hinted in his comment, the code you have shown omits two vital parts:

- The implementation of `GetLogEntries()`
- The invocation of the various `Case<n>` methods

I would be extremely surprised if the `Buffer` implementation is broken. Also, the code you have shown correctly calls the `Buffer` overloads.

Therefore the most likely explanation is that the problem is in the omitted code.

I note that you are calling `GetLogEntries()` on an instance (`this.LogsProvider`) that is possibly shared between `Case3` and `Case4`. I strongly suspect this is the case and that your invocation of `GetLogEntries()` is not idempotent and has side effects causing the second invocation to return no entries. Does it perhaps return the latest unreported log entries each time?

Comment: I was pretty sure from the start that I was doing something wrong, and never assumed that the Buffer implementation was wrong. I just had a nice bug in my GetLogEntries() which I didn't realize, because case 3 would fire as expected.

Comment: Did you write a test for it when you found it? ;) Glad it's sorted.

Comment: No, I just reviewed that bit of code a couple of days later, and it was shouting at me: TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds, not TimeSpan.Milliseconds! (The latter was always 0 because my logs didn't log milliseconds.)